# Extract the common rows between multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I am trying to merge multiple dataframes and create a new dataframe containing only the common the rows. For example:

The dataframes that i have as input:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Co8q.png)
The dataframe that i want to have as output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9A7f.png)

Do you know if there is a way to do that? If you could help me, i would be more than thankfull!!
Thanks,
Eleni

Answer (score 1):

You want [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', indicator=False)
        .merge(df3, how='inner', indicator=False)
```